# Convert france character to HTML special character

Tags: php, zend-framework, special-characters

I'm using Zend framework with mongoDB. I need to convert France character to special character. 

 For example: Prénom -> `Pr&eacute;nom` . what could I do?

Answer (score 2):

`htmlentities` ( http://php.net/htmlentities ) can do this if you call:

```
htmlentities('Prénom', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

I get:

```
Pr&eacute;nom
```

as the result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at strtr function (Read more at http://php.net/strtr)?

Comment: I want to convert Prénom to `Pr&eacute;nom`.

Comment: That means you want to convert it to convert string into html entities?

Comment: That mean I want to insert `Pr&eacute;nom` into my database.

Comment: Then `htmlentities` should serve the purpose, as suggested by @Sammaye.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way to look is either [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Here is an example which you can view [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13d7d5c9c4074ec2f75127cbc48f8dac3c8bdcf0):

```
$text = "Prénom"; 
echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
echo "\n";
echo htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```